# Windows 8 home screen not visible after booting and entering password

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, reboot, start-screen

i have re-started my laptop with windows 8 OS several times over. But I am stuck. the following is happening :
I put the power button on. Then it asks for password. I enter the password. But nothing shows up. Only a blank screen shows up. The laptop is unable to boot through to the home sceen.
Can someone help me out ? thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

My first suspect would be video driver/card.

Try going in safe mode and if safe mode works fine, it's definitely your video driver/card. Try reinstalling driver. If the problem still persist, try using another video card (or onboard one) - assuming the problem you're experiencing is on PC.

Comment: how should i re-install the driver ? how to uninstall it ? I am a newbee wrt windows 8.. please guide.

Comment: should i go for safe mode with networking option ?

Comment: Safe mode with networking will do if you're going to reinstall/update. If you see desktop and you're able to access files, then my bet is on video driver.

Comment: yes, I am able to c the desktop in safe mode and access the files too. what should I do next ? I am in safe mode right now

Comment: Right click on Window icon, choose Device Manager, find and extend Display adapters. You have two options now: 1) Right click on chosen display adapter and Uninstall. Then reboot PC. Don't worry, it's safe. Upon system start the video drivers will auto update. 2) Right click and choose Update Driver Software, then select Search automatically. Feel free to go with first option.

Comment: kz.. I am a bit skeptical about uninstalling the display adapter. It is showing graphics card. are u sure on uninstalling this graphic card, there won't be any further complications ? is there any other way round ? I have a Viao laptop

Comment: It should be ok. Windows have their own video driver they use for safe mode etc and they work until update finds proper drivers that are made especially for your video card. Edit: if all else fails, there's still system restore but that sounds like one of last case scenarios.

Comment: should i go into the safe mode again after re-boot ? I have uninstalled the driver

Comment: No, just do the normal start up.After start up, leave PC for auto update drivers. If shouldn't take more than a few minutes (also depending on how many services and programs start at boot on your laptop).

Comment: when the PC is auto updating the drivers, does it show the status of updation too ? cuz nothing of such notice is visible on the screen. how would I know whether it is really updating the drivers  ?

Comment: No, usually it does not show anything when it's auto updating. In the case of video driver, what you *may* notice is that your monitor will either flicker or go dark for a few seconds, then come back on. When it's back on, it means the driver has been reinstalled and it's up & running. HOWEVER, if after update you reboot again and the same problem comes back on, then you *may* have a more serious problem.

Comment: yeah I am facing the same problem again .. screen is blank after start up. yikes.

Comment: My similar problem is that Win8.1 won't turn off or shut down without freezing followed by hard reset (pushing the power button until the laptop shuts down.) and I found out that it's video drivers fault (in my case it's Radeon). Everything works well on Linux, but I guess I'm stuck with freezing until Windows 10 is out and hopefully they'll come with better drivers.